# Как сделать циклический таймер на js?

Tags: jquery, ajax, время, javascript

Необходимо сделать циклический таймер на js/jQuery (Что типа такого: "Осталось 00:00:42"), в котором будет учитываться часовой пояс посетителя сайта. Также нужно сделать, чтобы на последних секундах цифры меняли цвет, например на красный. Как это можно реализовать? Есть ли что готовое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Да навалом вариантов, собственно...](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=countdown)
Чаще всего хватает первого.

Comment: Как реализовать последнее условие?

Comment: что такое "последнее условие"?..

Comment: @deivan, "нужно сделать, чтобы на последних секундах цифры меняли цвет, например на красный"

Comment: для начала выберите подходящий таймер, а потом напишите, что конкретно с ним не получается - выполнять работу за вас, это нарушение правил этого ресурса

Comment: @deivan, никто и не просит делать работу за меня. Мне нужно само логическое решение

Comment: @XenK, когда сделаете простой таймер, станет понятно, в каком месте проверять оставшееся до конца время, и вписать дополнительное действие по раскраске в красный цвет )